# How to align logo and text in bootstrap on small screens?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to align a logo and some text within a bootstrap nav bar.

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g8za882k/)

I have the following html :

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
  <img class="hidden-xs" src="http://s23.postimg.org/5k9xcsb57/logo40_ul.png" alt="">
  <img class="visible-xs" src="http://s23.postimg.org/etc3mwk13/logo30_ul.png" alt="">
  <span class="navbar-brand-text">Some text here</span>
</a>
```

And this CSS :

```
.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0px;
}

.navbar-brand-text {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.875em;
  line-height: 1.57em;
}
.navbar-brand img {
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-top: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-brand {
    padding: 0px;
  }

  .navbar-brand-text {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0.875em;
    line-height: 1.57em;
  }
  .navbar-brand img {
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

I've had some success when the screen is at full width, but on mobile sizes the Logo and the Text stack on top of each other not next to each other.

How do I align my image with my text in a nav bar so :

1. it remains side by side regardless of screen size and;
2. I have some control over the vertical position of the logo / text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a rule `display: block!important;` on the logo, which make it like that. Changing it like below should do do job.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-brand .visible-xs {
        display: inline; /* use !important if necessary */
    }
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/g8za882k/3/

Comment: I see. Thank you. Can I ask you the process you used to tracked that down (or did you just know it)? I was inspecting the various elements in the developer tools but it certainly wasn't obvious. The irony was that I tried various things to override the display: properties. Is that the clue? If an override isn't working look for an !important? Or is it time to lean Less and trawl through the source files?

Comment: @dwkns I was doing the same, because normally we use display: none and block together, i through that would be it, and of course a block rule will make it to falls to a new line, so use inline or inline-block instead, problem solved.